# import matplotlib.pyplot gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I try to import matplotlib.pyplt in Pycharm console

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then in return I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-eff513f636fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2512, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 165, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 125, in enable_gui
    raise UsageError("%s" % e)
UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'qt5', valid ones are:['pyglet', 'osx', 'none', 'gtk3', 'tk', 'qt', 'glut', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'wx']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\events.py", line 74, in trigger
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 147, in post_execute
    if matplotlib.is_interactive():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'
Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x0000000008AAD438> (for post_execute):
```

My python version：

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

But when I try to import matplotlib in Ipython, it works. Is there something wrong with my Pycharm console?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Identical Applications, version numbers and almost identical error. Unfortunately I also do not have a solution.

Comment: @Chao Any luck so far?

Comment: `import matplotlib as mpl`

`mpl.use('TkAgg')`

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`  and it works

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same problem and proble is resolved after i upgraded pyCharm to 2016.03 version.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the opposite problem in that starting Ipython failed with the same error `(matplotlib.is_interactive())`

I had `%pylab inline` as part of my Ipython startup settings (`~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/start.ipy`) that was messing things up, and removing it cleared up the issue.  This started occurring after updating my version of Ipython and Anaconda.

My thought is something similar is happening behind the scenes for you.  Perhaps setting up a similar startup script to do the *opposite* with the code @Chao provided might work.