# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'

Tags: python, image, ipython, importerror

This is my python code. It's objective is to take in two images from the file system then produce plots based on the analysis of the images.

I installed the Anaconda package and I'm working in iPython on Windows 10 (Python 2.7).

When I run my code I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'

I ensured that the folders with my images exist in the file system.

```
# Bring in necessary libraries
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from skimage import color
import skimage.filters as filters
from skimage.transform import hough_circle
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import feature
from skimage import morphology
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage import img_as_float, img_as_ubyte
from skimage import segmentation as seg
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage as nd
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
from skimage import feature
import glob # for bulk file import

# Set defaults
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray' # Display grayscale images in... grayscale.
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'none' # Use nearest-neighbour
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 10

# Import test images
imgpaths = glob.glob("C:\\images\\ * .jpg") + glob.glob("C:\\images\\ * .png")
imgset = [img_as_ubyte(mpimg.imread(x)) for x in imgpaths]

# Display thumbnails of the images to ensure loading
plt.figure()
for i,img in enumerate(imgset):
    plt.subplot(1, len(imgset), i+1)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')

# Plots a histogram of the image, splitting into individual channels if necessary.
def plot_multichannel_histo(img):
    if img.ndim == 2: # plot grayscale histo
        plt.hist(img.flatten(), 256, range=(0,255), color='k', histtype='step')
    elif img.ndim == 3: # print rgb histo
        plt.hist(img.reshape(-1,3), 256, range=(0,255), color=['r','g','b'],histtype='step')
    else: # Not an image
        print("Must pass a valid RGB or grayscale image")
    plt.xlim([0,255])

 # Apply to test images
for i,img in enumerate(imgset):
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plot_multichannel_histo(img)
```

iPython spits this out:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownBackend                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bcf46d40fe9f> in <module>()
      1 # Bring in necessary libraries
----> 2 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import matplotlib.image as mpimg
      5 import numpy as np

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2156         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2157         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2158         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2159
   2160     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2077                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2078             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2079                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2080             return result
   2081

<decorator-gen-105> in matplotlib(self, line)

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189
    190         if callable(arg):

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)
     98             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
     99         else:
--> 100             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
    101             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    102

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2945                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2946
-> 2947         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2948         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2949

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.pyc in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    292     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    293
--> 294     import matplotlib.pyplot
    295     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    296

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
   2533 # are no-ops and the registered function respect `mpl.is_interactive()`
   2534 # to determine if they should trigger a draw.
-> 2535 install_repl_displayhook()
   2536
   2537 ################# REMAINING CONTENT GENERATED BY boilerplate.py ##############

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in install_repl_displayhook()
    164             ipython_gui_name = backend2gui.get(get_backend())
    165             if ipython_gui_name:
--> 166                 ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
    167         else:
    168             _INSTALL_FIG_OBSERVER = True

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.pyc in enable_gui(self, gui)
    450     def enable_gui(self, gui=None):
    451         if gui:
--> 452             self._inputhook = get_inputhook_func(gui)
    453         else:
    454             self._inputhook = None

C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\pt_inputhooks\__init__.pyc in get_inputhook_func(gui)
     36
     37     if gui not in backends:
---> 38         raise UnknownBackend(gui)
     39
     40     if gui in aliases:

UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for 'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, pyglet, glut, osx
Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x0000000006E06908> (for post_execute):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in post_execute()
    146
    147             def post_execute():
--> 148                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
    149                     draw_all()
    150

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'
Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x0000000006E06908> (for post_execute):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in post_execute()
    146
    147             def post_execute():
--> 148                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
    149                     draw_all()
    150

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_interactive'
```

Comment: what line does the error occur on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import matplotlib.pyplot gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is\_interactive'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255191/import-matplotlib-pyplot-gives-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribut)

Comment: Not quite sure, I added the error message. I think it might be "imgset = [img_as_ubyte(mpimg.imread(x)) for x in imgpaths]". I think my program either can't find or import the images.